# php parser error I cannot solve

Tags: php, syntax-error

I'm a php beginner and am having a problem finding out why my code keeps throwing up a parser error. Hope you guys can help me out.

The error comes at the end of the code and is "Unexpected , expecting while (T_WHILE)"
The code is here...

```
<html>
  <?php
     $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testit;charset=UTF-8', 'testit', 'testit', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
 PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

     $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TestTable");

     $amdata = array();
     $ctrinner = 0;
     $ctrouter = -1;
     $prevweek = "9999";


     while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) do {
        if ($prevweek !== $row['WeekNumber']) {
            $ctrouter++;
            $ctrinner = 0;
            $amdata[$ctrouter][$ctrinner] = 'week: "'+$row['WeekNumber']+'"';
       }
        $ctrinner++;
        $amdata[$ctrouter][$ctrinner] = $row['XAxisCategory']+': '+$row['YAxisValue'];
        $prevweek = $row['WeekNumber'];
     }
     // Whatever comes aftert this line throws a php error 'Unexpected <whatever I put there>, expecting while (T_WHILE)....'
     // Even if I put nothing it complains about Unexpected '?>' expecting while (T_WHILE)  ?>
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your do-while loop is wrong.

A do-while loop looks like:

```
 do {
     /* loop  body */
 } while (/* condition */);
```

But in your special case, I'd simply omit the `do` keyword:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   /* loop body */
}
```